# My Laptop has USB 3.0 but Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't recognize it?

Tags: 14.04, usb, ssd

I have two USB 3.0 ports in my dell inspiron 5421 laptop . The ports marked as `SS` meaning super speed. But when I run the command `lspci -t` this is the output

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

and the output of `lsusb` is below

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:649a Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As is shown, none of the command shows the presence of a Super Speed USB port. I never actually checked it before but currently I am thinking to buy a portable 256Gb SSD, that's why I am checking if the port would be a bottleneck for the Drive.

Here is the output of `lsmod | grep hcd; lspci -nnk | grep "USB controller" -A2`

```
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0591]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci


00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0591]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsmod | grep hcd;

lspci -nnk | grep "USB controller" -A2`

Comment: Edited  the output.

Comment: Try a `echo 'xhci_hcd' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules` and reboot for a better feeling =)

Comment: Try a `echo 'xhci_hcd' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`

Comment: Still same , nothing has changed after reboot ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the USB 3 ports appear in the BIOS and are not disabled.

Rami Rosen