# No USB ports are detected on 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb

**EDIT:**   I'm using a [HP ENVY Desktop - 750-450ng](https://support.hp.com/rs-en/document/c05323528) with a new PSU and a RTX2070

**EDIT2:**
For anyone who has the same problem, it has solved itself, all USB ports are now working. I do not know why and that annoys me

I'm freshly switched from Win10 to Ubunutu 20.04 and this is my first time using Linux for an extended period of time. Please forgive me for obvious beginner mistakes.

After reinstalling Ubunutu 20.04 everything worked,Bluetooth and also all USB ports (USB-A & -C, 2.0 & 3.0). Hard drives, mouse and keyboard were all recognized.
I was also able to get into the BIOS (all USB ports were marked as active there).

After updates and a reboot, none of the USB ports work now, Bluetooth is not recognized either.I can't access the Bios because the keyboard is not recognized at boot time. But the ports have Energy, I can load devices from the ports.

I had to install a PCI card with extra USB ports so I can write this.

I found a few other questions, some of which were similar, however none of them solved my problem.

[legacy support in BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726007/front-usb-ports-dont-detect-anything) -> I have not found a suitable option in the BIOS (checked with the reinstalled version)

[dead question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331454/usb-port-not-detected-20-04)

[broken motherboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126618/usb-ports-detected-but-not-active-on-ubuntu-18-04) -> ports worked fine on the fresh install

[legacy support in BIOS again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729558/how-do-i-get-usb-3-0-driver-working-or-check-that-it-is-already-working) -> still no matching option seen in BIOS

[duplicate of the above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711483/my-laptop-has-usb-3-0-but-ubuntu-14-04-doesnt-recognize-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

On Win 10 I had the same problem with the XHCI driver, when solving the problem I got into a boot loop with bluescreen so I switched to Ubunutu.

I suspect also here a faulty XHCI driver, installed with the updates.

How can I use the driver from the installation ?

Here now the output of a few commands I found in the other questions (there was always a USB stick (3.0) and a mobile phone (UBS-C) connected):

### lsusb -t

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
```

### grep -i xhci /boot/config-$(uname -r)

```
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_DBGCAP=y
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_PCI=m
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_PCI_RENESAS=m
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_PLATFORM=m
CONFIG_USB_ROLES_INTEL_XHCI=m
```

### lspci -v | grep xhci

```
Kernel modules: xhci_pci
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
```

### lsmod | grep hcd; lspci -nnk | grep "USB controller" -A2

```
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [103c:828a]
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
--
01:00.2 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller [10de:1ada] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller [10de:12fe]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
--
05:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1b73:1100] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1b73:1100]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Comment: What is your system (if prebuilt) or your morherboard model number? Could you add these to the question?

Comment: Ah, you say your BIOS can't see your keyboard after rebooting _either_, so you can't get to the BIOS setup utility. Now that is an issue. I honestly think hardware is somewhere at fault here, because if the system firmware cannot access the keyboard, no operating system will.

Comment: @galexite With a fresh installation (without apt-get update/upgrade) the ports work fine

Comment: Is that RTX 2070 a custom addition? Have you tried removing the GPU (if you can use integrated graphics on that motherboard, or replacing the existing GPU) and additional PCI USB card to see if that makes a difference? My experience with prebuilt machines is that they can get 'freaked out' by significant hardware upgrades.

Comment: Even with a fresh installation though, you still cannot reach the system firmware settings? On the integrated USB ports?

Comment: Also, your GPU has an integrated USB-C port, did you try that as well? The original GPU would not have a port, and the new GPU would possibly supply the xHCI driver for the system firmware as an option ROM. This is why I'm concerned about the addition of the GPU.

Comment: @galexite The configuration with the new GPU has been like this for almost a year.
Under Win10 I have removed and tested the components without success.
With Ubuntu I have not done that yet.
I can't find the USB-C port, maybe my mini version doesn't have one (I still have to find out the exact model).

With a fresh installation, the ports work: I plug in the USB port, boot the PC, install Ubunutu, remove the stick and then everything works fine. At that point I have not yet installed any updates

Comment: Ah, okay. I just see problems within the firmware, designed specifically to be used with the onboard controller, which doesn't care about the drivers in the operating system, as a big red flag. You shouldn't be having issues with the USB in the firmware at the _very_ least. Your `lspci -nnk` output shows that one of the USB controllers is a `NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller`, which has the internal identifier for your RTX 2070. Maybe it is for an internal GPU service (unlikely), or for another port (maybe DisplayPort, or Thunderbolt)?

Comment: Even after rebooting (try a cold and a warm reboot, i.e. shut down, and boot up by the case's power button for a cold, or restart from the system menu for warm) on a fresh install, do the USB ports still work? Is your system firmware up to date? Can you install an SSH server, and remotely access the system from another machine when the USB ports don't work, to collect any system logs from the problematic Ubuntu updates?

Comment: Not suggesting this as any kind of solution, but useful to know - you can get an on-screen keyboard via 'Universal access' in Settings. I know you couldn't realistically type your whole detailed question with mouse clicks, but it's a useful tip if you want to try command line solutions with a non-functioning keyboard.